# How to associate a function with every item in the listWidget?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

My objective is when open button is clicked, it will display all the files in the directory. When you click any of the directory it will display the content of the directory in an another frame. Now how will I connect each item in the list to a function which will grab the contents of the directory. Here is my code:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 201))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self.frame)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 201))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 120, 80))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), self.add)

    #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), self.test)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def add(self):
    item=[]
    item = os.listdir('.')
    for value in item:
        self.listWidget.addItem(value)

    def test(self):
    print 'hello'   

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simpler way is to use these two signals:

```
itemClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)
```

or

```
itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)
```

from the QListWidget.

For example:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem)"), self.test)
```

which it should call the self.test method passing the current QListWidgetItem as parameter.

Comment: Oh, right. The connect line is `QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *)"), self.test)`, note the star in the signal specification and the test method should be defined as `def test(self, item)`

Comment: Is there a way to set it to a single click or whenever the item is selected. Basically I don't want the user to double click. Is it possible to set it based on the selection of an item rather than doubleclick.

Comment: use `itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)`